# Find Illustrator files with missing fonts without opening the files

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts

I have over 2000 adobe illustrator files and some of them have missing fonts (i don't know which). Is it possible to search through the files without opening them in adobe illustrator to determine which ones have the missing fonts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Without opening the file there's no way Illustrator can know what fonts are active on the system and what fonts are not.

I don't think this really helps but.....

If the files were saved with PDF compatibility you can open the files with Acrobat and check the properties to list the fonts in the document (without fonts being seen as "missing"). This *may* help you determine which fonts you have and which you don't... but it's *still* opening the file.

Comment: Well, that kind of sucks, but that is sort of what I expected. I wonder if when I export them all automatically with an action, illustrator will warn me that a file is missing a font? If not, I will have to open every single one and check.